# Port forwarding beginner

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, port-forwarding

I have been trying to set up port forwarding for the past 48 hours and I can't quite get it. I have used online port scanners to see what ports are open and they are saying none, not even the port I opened myself.

What I did:

1. Logged onto my router website.
2. Enabled DMZ with my computers IP.
3. In the port forwarding option, allowed TCP and UDP on the port I selected.
4. Enabled a Static IP address for my node.
5. Made an exception to the port in the firewall.
6. Use a port scanner and to no avail.

Is there any steps I have missed?  This will be used for reverse shell/connect back in python scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You may already be doing this, but I know that when I try those port scanners they only tell me the port is open when I'm broadcasting e.g. the server I'm running is up. **You might have to be using the port for the scanner to work.**

Although, my situation may be different as all I need to do to get mine working is steps 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You dont wantto put your computer in the DMZ for port forwarding.  Actually, that's fairly dangerous.  Here is a great article on [port forwarding](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/).

Think of it this way, if you want to allow web access to an internal computer, you want to forward port 80 from your router to your PC running the webserver.  Your router has the public IP assigned to you by your ISP.  Your *router* is what is connected to the Internet.  Your router is also most likely your DHCP server, which gives your internal network, private IP addresses.  Your home network is not directly connected to the Internet, and thats why you need to forward the port from your router to your PC.  The router sends any incoming web traffic (port 80) to the PC.